# Connect a slider to control zoom on iOS Camera App

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimage, uislider

I am learning Xcode and am playing around with the SquareCam sample code app that Apple provides.

What I want to do is to be able to zoom in and out of the image with a slider object rather than the gesture.

How can I do this? Thank you!